# Why choose a binary(16) PK instead of a compound key?

Tags: mysql, npm

Looking at the MySQL schema used for npm's download counts: https://github.com/npm/download-counts/blob/master/test/schema.sql#L3, why would they opt for a binary PK *and* a unique index on (package, day) instead of using the (package, day) tuple as a compound key?

Is there a performance/storage concern with using the compound key as the only key (dropping the binary(16) key) at their scale?

Comment: It's generally a good idea if a PK monotonously grows or decreases (since that's how rows are physically laid out on the disk). With `package-day` key it would not be the case. "Is there a performance/storage concern with the compound key at their scale" --- they have a compound key `UNIQUE KEY package-day (package(255),day),`. Plus a primary key is appended to every other key implicitly, so the smaller it is - the better.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I'll update the ending question as I meant having the compound key replace the binary(16) PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design decision is usually the result of weighing the tradeoffs.

In terms of storage, in the more general case, there may be other tables that have foreign key references to the table. That primary key value will be need to be stored as a reference. With the primary key is a composite key, all of the primary key columns will also need to be stored in the referencing table. Using a shorter, single column as a primary key means only that shorter value will need to be stored in referencing tables.

Also, if there are any secondary indexes on the table, (in InnoDB) the primary key value is also stored in the secondary index, as the reference to the row. (In InnoDB, the primary key serves as the cluster key.)

Some designers consider some desirable attributes of the "ideal" primary key. These are not all hard requirements for a primary key, but these are desirable for several reasons:

- unique (no duplicate values)
- non-null (a value will always be assigned)
- immutable (one assigned, it will not change)
- anonymous (carries no "meaning")
- simple (single column, native datatype)

If any of the columns in the primary key carries some meaning, that may lead to a requirement to allow a columns in the primary key to be changed. In terms of performance, an update of the primary key will potentially mean relocating rows in the table, and changes in to secondary indexes.  This may also lead to a requirement to add another immutable identifier, for simplifying integration with other systems.

Following a consistent pattern for primary keys (name and datatype) across all tables, that's a consistent pattern that can be a benefit for developers, especially in ORM frameworks.

If all tables have a primary key which is a single column named `id`, all of the same datatype, then that's a consistent pattern which simplifies some development patterns. And frequently, the foreign key columns take on names like `referenced_table_name_id`. In SQL, this leads to consistent join patterns, e.g.

```
   FROM foo
   JOIN bar
     ON bar.foo_id = foo.id
```

Following this pattern, odd or unusual SQL looks odd or unusual. SQL that uses "wrong" join predicates also looks odd and unusual... e.g.

```
    FROM foo f
    JOIN bar b
      ON foo.id = bar.id
```

(looks like a primary key matches primary key)

```
    FROM foo f
    JOIN bar b
      ON foo.somecol = bar.somecol
```

(from just looking at the SQL, it seems ambiguous which table is the parent and which is the child... in which table is somecol the primary key?

---

To summarize, there can be lots of reasons for the design decisions that are made. I've provided just a short list of some reasons that designers/developers may have chosen to use a single, short column named `id` as the primary key of this table.

Comment: The surrogate key is also useful to avoid the PK limit of 767 bytes. NPM's schema supports package names of length 2000, which makes it unfit for a PK.